# ExtJS4: nested RESTfull resource urls at depths > 1 using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, extjs4

(Contrived) example collection urls:

```
VERB /leagues
VERB /leagues/{leagueId}/teams
VERB /leagues/{leagueId}/teams/{teamId}/players
```

The goal is to configure my associations and proxies to automatically target these urls.

Currently, I have a model for each of *League*, *Team*, and *Player*, with a **hasMany** association chain in the direction of

> (League) ---hasMany--> (Team) ---hasMany--> (Player)

with the the Id's of the owning model used as the foreign key in the associated model. 
(I.e. each `Team` has a `leagueId` which equals the `id` of it's owning `League`, and each `Player` has a `TeamId` which equals the `id` of it's owning `Team`)

One attempt at solving this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854420/accessing-complex-rest-resources-with-ext-js). However, it didn't work for me. My initial attempt was overriding the `buildUrl` method of the proxies as:

```
    buildUrl: function(request) {
        var url = this.getUrl(request),
            ownerId = request.operation.filters[0].value;

        url = url.replace('{}', ownerId);

        request.url = url;
        return Ext.data.proxy.Rest.superclass.buildUrl
            .apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

Which works *perfectly* for a url resource depth of 1 (`VERB /leagues/{leagueId}/teams`). The problem is when I do something like:

```
League.load(1, {
   callback: function(league) {
       league.teams().load({
           callback: function(teams) {
               // all good so far
               var someTeam = teams[0];
               someTeam.players().load({
                    // problem here. someTeam.players() does not have a filter 
                    // with leagueId as a value. Best you can do is 
                    // GET/leagues/undefined/teams/42/players
               });
           }
       });
   }
});
```

What do I need to override in order to get all the information I need to build the url in the `buildUrl` methods? I don't want to manually add a filter each time - that sort of defeats the purpose and I might aswel set the proxy each time.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current (working) solution I came up with was to modify the `constructor` of internal resources and manually add filters to the generated stores there. For example:

**App.models.Team**

```
constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.players().filters.add(new Ext.util.Filter({
        property: 'leagueId',
        value: this.raw.leagueId
    }));
    return this;
},
```

and that way all the filter property:value pairs are available in the `buildUrl` methods via `request.operation.filters`.

I'll accept this answer for now (since it works), but will accept another answer if a better one is suggested.