# How to access complex REST resources with ExtJS 5

Tags: rest, extjs, extjs5

I am using ExtJS 5 and I want to access complex REST resources as discussed [in this similar thread using ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854420/accessing-complex-rest-resources-with-ext-js).

The REST service that I am accessing exposes these resources:

- GET `/rest/clients` - it returns a list of clients
- GET `/rest/users` - it returns a list of all users
- GET `/rest/clients/{clientId}/users` - it returns a list of users from the specified client.

I have these models:

```js
Ext.define('App.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    schema: {
        namespace: 'App.model'
    }
});

Ext.define('App.model.Client', {
    extend: 'App.model.Base',
    
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    proxy: {
        url: 'rest/clients',
        type: 'rest'
    }
});

Ext.define('App.model.User', {
    extend: 'App.model.Base',
    
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'clientId',
        reference: 'Client'
    }],
    
    proxy: {
        url: 'rest/users',
        type: 'rest'
    }
});
```

I did this:

```js
var client = App.model.Client.load(2);
var users = client.users().load();
```

And it sent, respectively:

> //GET rest/clients/2
> //GET rest/users?filter:[{"property":"personId","value":"Person-1","exactMatch":true}]

## Questions:

1. Is there any way that I can send my request to "`GET rest/clients/2/users`" **without** updating the user proxy url manually with its clientId?
2. How can I send above request without losing the original url defined in App.model.User, "`rest/users`"

Answer (score 0):

I think this essentially the same as this question:

[Accessing complex REST resources with Ext JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854420/accessing-complex-rest-resources-with-ext-js)

I don't think much has changed since it was first asked.